# jQuery ajax xml import node into document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

```
function getNewMonth(month, year, table) {
    "use strict";
    var uri, newTable;
    uri = 'ajax.php?m=' + month + '&y=' + year;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {
            newTable = document.importNode(xml.getElementsByTagName('table')[0], true);
            $(table).replaceWith(newTable);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't do much with ajax but I understand the xml from the server is part of a different document than the web page. Not finding a jQuery way to import, I used the standard JS importNode.

When this function runs, the old table is replaced with the new, but it is not rendered. The text content is displayed but not in a rendered table.

Inspect element shows all the tags are there, but both browsers I tried (FireFox and Midori) don't render the table.

What the bleep am I doing wrong?

The response from the server is valid XML using a standard html table and child nodes, and is generated by the exact same php code on the server that generated the rendered table it is replace - just a different month and year.

Clearly there is something I am not comprehending here.

I appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT -

Here is what the ajax response looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table style="float: left; width: 800px; background: url('PNG/RitaCalendar.png') no-repeat bottom;" cellspacing="0px" class="sexycal" data-year="2016" data-month="7" data-ete="Mistress Rita" data-uri="http://www.kinkonomics.com/">
  <caption><span title="Previous Month">◀</span>   July 2016   <span title="Next Month">▶</span></caption>
  <tr height="40px">
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Sunday</th>
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Monday</th>
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Tuesday</th>
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Humpday</th>
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Thursday</th>
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Friday</th>
    <th scope="col" valign="top" width="14.28%">Saturday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr height="133px">
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">1</td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="133px">
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">3<br/><span class="mname"><a href="http://www.kinkadvisor.com/" target="_blank">Marilyn</a></span><br/><span class="wlist"><a href="http://www.amazon.com/registry/wishlist/43T049UULTFM" target="_blank">Wishlist</a></span></td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">4</td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">5</td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">6</td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">7</td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">8</td>
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">9</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more of the same -->
  <tr height="133px">
    <td class="data" valign="top" align="right">31<br/><span class="mname"><a href="http://www.fetishphonesexcalls.com/" target="_blank">EmmaJane</a></span><br/><span class="wlist"><a href="http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/2Y3GT6EEWXW20" target="_blank">Wishlist</a></span></td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And if it matters, this is the php

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$reqmonth = dateObject($y, $m);

$table = monthTable($db,$xml,$reqmonth);
$xml->appendChild($table);
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
//avoid caching
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in past
print($xml->saveXML());
exit;
```

monthTable() is the same function used to generate the table in the web page as originally served.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what newTable looks like? Is it a standard html table?

Answer (score 0):

It works if I do it is text instead of xml-

```
function getNewMonth(month, year, table) {
    "use strict";
    var uri, newTable;
    uri = 'ajax.php?m=' + month + '&y=' + year;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (text) {
            $('#caldiv').prepend(text);
            $(table).remove();
            attachEvents();
        }
    });
}
```

So it appears that for some reason, importNode allows adding the node to the DOM tree but it does not trigger render refresh. But the above works so I'll just stick with that.